# How to add extral sample data into PCA result but will not change the original scale?

Tags: r, pca

I recently drawed PCA plot with data wine.
**But I want to add another data into PCA with original scale?**
Shall I describe that in this way? Or **`project in`** ?

Thanks a lot.

Here is my PCA data and code:

```
library(ggalt)
library(ggbiplot)
data(wine)

wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, scale. = TRUE)

ggbiplot(wine.pca,
  obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1,
  groups = wine.class, ellipse = F, circle = F
) +
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.position = "top") +
  geom_point(aes(color = wine.class), size = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Saturday", values = c("red", "green", "blue"), aesthetics = c("color", "fill")) +
  geom_encircle(aes(fill = wine.class), alpha = 0.3, show.legend = F, colour = NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I find the perfect answer [here](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/pca-analysis-r)! Thank godness.

Here is the original code:

```
mtcars
dim(mtcars)
mtcars.country <- c(rep("Japan", 3), rep("US",4), rep("Europe", 7),rep("US",3), "Europe", rep("Japan", 3), rep("US",4), rep("Europe", 3), "US", rep("Europe", 3))

mtcars.pca <- prcomp(mtcars[,c(1:7,10,11)], center = TRUE,scale. = TRUE)

summary(mtcars.pca)

##
spacecar <- c(1000,60,50,500,0,0.5,2.5,0,1,0,0)

mtcarsplus <- rbind(mtcars, spacecar)
mtcars.countryplus <- c(mtcars.country, "Jupiter")
mtcarsplus.pca <- prcomp(mtcarsplus[,c(1:7,10,11)], center = TRUE,scale. = TRUE)

## 
ggbiplot(mtcars.pca,ellipse=TRUE,obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1,  labels=rownames(mtcars), groups=mtcars.country) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Origin", values= c("forest green", "red3", "dark blue"))+
  ggtitle("PCA of mtcars dataset")+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
##
ggbiplot(mtcarsplus.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, ellipse = TRUE, circle = FALSE, var.axes=TRUE, labels=c(rownames(mtcars), "spacecar"), groups=mtcars.countryplus)+
  scale_colour_manual(name="Origin", values= c("forest green", "red3", "violet", "dark blue"))+
  ggtitle("PCA of mtcars dataset, with extra sample added")+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```